# How can I modify Kruskal's algorithm to work with limited resources?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

In Kruskal algorithm, I decided to use it to construct a minimum spanning tree for a set of N = 100,000 points. Since my hardware does not allow me to keep all the distances between pairs of points, I decided to define the potential edges of the graph in batches of k * N edges (starting of course with the K * N shortest edges, and subsequent batches to compute only when necessary; prior to checking, it seems to me that k = 5 would be appropriate).

Please suggest the implementation of the functions determining k * N edges, so that could be used in the Kruskal algorithm.

Comment: Do you use external sort? Have you seen the paper about [external MST](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/dementiev/files/emst.pdf)? It uses semi-external Kruskal algorithm. What are your limitations? (I assume RAM, but maybe it is both RAM and disk space?)

Comment: So, your problem is how to store a big complete graph that doesn't fit into memory?